# IDL getting file size

Tags: filesize, idl-programming-language

I'm currently using IDL (Interactive Data Language) and I'm looking for a way to get the size of a file. Does anyone knows a solution?

To be more specific: 
I've got an array of Strings containing filenames and a function iterates through those files and should generate a new array of filesizes as a side effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
file_sizes = (file_info(filenames)).size
```